# Rails activerecord get collection of collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models

```
User has_many :events
Event has_many :advertisements
```

Now I simply want to **show all advertisements of a user**.

I tried:

```
@user.events.joins(:advertisements).all
@user.events.advertisements.all
@user.events.all.advertisements.all
```

and various other combinations but I might get something wrong here after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use has many through to get rails to do the joins for you.

```
class User
  has_many :events
  has_many :advertisements, through: :events
end

user = User.first
user_ads = user.advertisements
```

If you don't want to do that though you can do

```
user = User.first
ads = Advertisement.joins(:event).where(events: { user_id: user.id })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should establish relationship between them like this

user.rb

```
has_many :events,dependent: :destroy
has_many :advertisements, through: :events
```

event.rb

```
has_many :advertisments,dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user
```

advertisement.rb

```
belongs_to :event
```

now you can access advertisement directly.

```
User.find(1).advertisements
```